# ¿Como 'desfragmentar' un arreglo para realizar un insert en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, array, funciones

En mi controlador realize el siguiente arreglo

```
$DataPerson=
        array(
                    'documentos' => $this->input->post('documentos'),
                    'num_identificacion' => $this->input->post('num_identificacion'),
                    'nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
                    'apellido' => $this->input->post('apellido'),
                    'sexo' => $this->input->post('sexo'));

$envio = $this->Person_model->insertPerson($DataPerson);
```

El modelo recibe el parametro:

```
public function insertPerson($DataPerson)
{

}
```

como puedo recorrer el `$DataPerson` para que pueda insertar esos datos a la DB?

Agradeceria el interes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un foreach indicando la llave y el valor de dicho campo de tu arreglo para así acceder a cada elemento según lo ocupes para tus insert:

```
foreach($DataPerson as $key => $value){
    echo "Llave: ".$key."=> Valor: ".$value; //Ejemplo de como accederías en cada iteración al valor
}
```

- $key representa el nombre que asocia el valor que guardas en tu arreglo, o en términos mundanos lo que está del lado izquierdo de `=>` en tu arreglo.
- $value es justamente el valor que buscas obtener para tus inserts, o lo que está del lado derecho de `=>` en tu arreglo.

Comment: Hola @Lixus gracias por tu interes, la duda esta en que una ves saque el valor de cada parametro el insert debo realizarlo afuera del foreach? si es asi como pasaria esos parametros que se estan recorriendo dentro del foreach?

Comment: Depende de cómo armes tu cadena de sql, usarías parámetros para después ligarlos a tu consulta? O los concatenarías directamente al string usando variables de php?

Comment: La verdad estoy un poco confundido, normalmente si mi tabla tiene 3 campos por ejemplo, entonces cuando hago el insert envio 3 parametros al modelo y en el sql pongo 'insert into campo1,campo2,campo3 values 'parametro1','parametro2','parametro3' pero como estoy enviando un arreglo ahi es donde no comprendo.

Comment: Necesitarías entonces armar la cadena de manera dinámica basándote en tu arreglo, con cada for each, ve concatenando los nombres de los campos y sus parámetros, claro que esto significará que tengas que modificar el insert del modelo.

Comment: podrias crear un ejemplo, si eres tan amable?

Answer (score 1):

**Usas algun FRAMEWORK?**

En tu controlador arma tu array con los mismos atributos de tu tabla una vez creado el arreglo, solo es cuestion de que lo pases al modelo ahi con la funcion `insert` hara el recorrido

Un parentesis nose como se llama tu tabla supuse un nombre

```
function insertPerson($DataPerson) {
            $this->db->insert("empleados", $DataPerson);    
            if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No comprendo aquí en qué momento recorres el arreglo para obtener los valores que busca el OP

Comment: @Lixus por eso primero le pregunto si usa algun FRAMEWORK

Comment: uso laravel pero no acostumbro a usar sentencias de esa manera sino  a lo comun si se puede decir asi. ('inser into.....');